# Collection being updated while performing stream operation java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of objects that are being updated on a regular basis from a couple of threads. While being updated I want to use a stream to filter some elements out.

For example; say I have list that is being updated regularly:

```
List<MyObject> myList
```

Now at some point in time I use stream on that list

```
List<MyObject> result =  
myList.stream().filter(myobj->myobjt.isValid()).collect(toList());
```

Is this thread-safe given that my list is being update from a couple of threads?

Comment: What List implementation are you using? How are you updating the list (adding to the end or other things)? What do you expect your stream to do with these updates (ignore/include/fail fast/something else)?

Comment: I use CopyOnWriteArrayList since I want thread safe collection. I  only add to the end of a list. I want my stream to do general things might it be filtering or update objects within the list. I just gave an example of filtering but it can be anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Javadoc of CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) states the following:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException. The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created.

So, yes, your code should be threadsafe. The stream will ignore all additions to the list after it has started.

Comment: I see.. and what if only one thread updates a list and another thread uses stream operation on that list?

Comment: I don't quite get how the snaphot style "never" changes the underlying array of the iterator. Any modification operation on COW will be `synchronized` and eventually call `setArray` on `volatile` list. So, the iterator could still potentially see modification if it has not reached that point yet. No?

Comment: @stdout: CopyOnWriteArrayList makes a copy of the underlying array when it is updated. The iterator will continue to work on the old, unchanged array that it was created with.

Comment: @Thilo So, even that copy eventually be written over the original one via `setArray` call, this would not intervene the one which the `COWIterator` started iterating over.